# Schedule task and .exe

Tags: task, exe, kill, schedule

I have a scheduled job running an executable file. if I stop the scheduled job then the code of the executable file will continue until the end of the code or it will be terminated abruptly? This job is on windows server 2003.

Comment: Vb 2003, windows server 2003. The exe updates the records of a table and i lose some updates. The task is running 24 hours every 2 minutes. And the schedule task stops if it runs for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a few month ago a new schedule task. It runs a bat file with this code:

**@echo off
  pushd
  tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" | find /i "chrome.exe" > nul ||(start 
  chrome.exe)
  pause**

I run chrome via a schedule task witch call the above bat file.
If chrome is running i do not run it again.